# converting a string attribute to an array of strings

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am working on a model in rails, which has a column type that can have more than one values. In other words, as the users enter data in its database, new values might also be entered for that column. So it is like a one-to-many association. However, since the number of values will be very few (maybe less than 10), I did not want to create a separate model for it. By mistake, I had defined it as a string, but now I want to make it an array of strings, which can grow. How can I do that?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Instead of describing what you are doing, [use code to explain yourself](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're looking for is the [serialize method](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/AttributeMethods/Serialization/ClassMethods/serialize).

Simply call `serialize :attribute_name, Array` in your model.

Comment: I did this, but then when in the console I checked it, it did not work. For example: myobject.attr_name="str1". Then when I write myobject.attr_name << "str2", it becomes "str1str2" instead of ["str1" , "str2"]!

Comment: The problem might be that with `myobject.attr_name="str1"` you're assigning a string and not an array of strings. Give `myobject.attr_name << "str1"` a try as attr_name is initialized as an empty array. If that doesn't work try `myobject.attr_name=["str1"]`. Afterwards please report back and let us know what worked.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Yes it seems that initialization has important effect. Both of the ways you mentioned, worked for me.